# The definition of Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

I have some confusion about the definition of Sobolev space for a real positive real $r>0$.

I know that for a positive integer $m>0$ and $p\geq 1$ and any subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$, we define the Sobolev space denoted by $W^{m,p}$ by 
$$W^{m,p}=\{f\in L^p : \text{the partial derivatives up to order m are in }   L^p   \}.$$
I am struggling with the definition of a Sobolev space by the summation with the Fourier coefficients. And I want also to know the general definition of Sobolev space for any real positive $r >0.$

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking specifically about the case $p=2$?

Comment: Fourier Transforms are generally defined for functions in $L^2$.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Well...there's more to it than that. At the very least, there is $L^2$ Fourier transform theory, tempered distribution Fourier transform theory, and $L^1$ Fourier transform theory. The former two have the nice property that the FT maps the space into itself.

Answer (score 1):

As explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space and here [Is $B^s_{p,p} = W^{s,p}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709099/is-bs-p-p-ws-p/3709151#3709151), there are several extensions of Sobolev spaces for non integer spaces: the Sobolev-Bessel spaces $H^{s,p} = F^s_{p,2} = (1-\Delta)^{-s/2} L^p$ and the Sobolev-Slobodeckij spaces $W^{s,p} = F^s_{p,p} = B^s_{p,p}$. More generally, the Besov spaces $B^s_{p,q}$ and the Triebel-Lizorkin spaces $F^s_{p,q}$ are intermediate spaces between Sobolev spaces of integer order.